# How to select XML element by xlink:href attribute with CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml, css-selectors, xlink

Does anyone know how to select a XML element by `xlink:href` attribute with CSS?

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp) for the usage, however it doesn't explain how to select it with CSS.

```
<book title="XQuery Kick Start">
  <description
    xlink:type="simple"
    xlink:href="http://book.com/images/XQuery.gif"
    xlink:show="new"> ... </description>
</book>
```

Comment: You might want to tell us how exactly you are receiving and consuming this XML. Although it is possible to use CSS to style XML or HTML, they are both very different, and answers to one may not always work for the other, as shown in my answer for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), you'd need to [**escape** the colon](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) `:` by a leading backslash`\`, as follows:

```css
description[xlink\:href="http://book.com/images/HPotter.gif"] {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <book title="Harry Potter">
    <description
      xlink:type="simple"
      xlink:href="http://book.com/images/HPotter.gif"
      xlink:show="new"> ... </description>
  </book>

  <book title="XQuery Kick Start">
    <description
      xlink:type="simple"
      xlink:href="http://book.com/images/XQuery.gif"
      xlink:show="new"> ... </description>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rajezugu/1/edit)**.

Comment: @user3143218: I would be surprised if this actually worked with an XML document as indicated in the question. If you're not in fact handling it as XML, though, then no complaints.

Comment: OK, I see that the original question had the [html] tag, so for all we know the OP could have intended to style it as HTML. You probably shouldn't have removed the tag then, especially if you were going to answer as if it were HTML anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 6):

The only way that escaping the colon with a backslash could possibly work is if you were receiving the document as XML but outputting it as HTML, stripping it of all its XML semantics.

If you're styling the XML document directly with CSS, the correct way is to [declare the `xlink` namespace at the top of your stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace) according to the [XLink spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/#att-method), like so:

```css
@namespace xlink 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
```

Then [use an attribute selector with a namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp) to target your element:

```css
description[xlink|href="http://book.com/images/XQuery.gif"] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Didn't work with SVG.use. For it use ` svg use[*|href="#mydef-id"] { } `.

Answer (score -1):

Treat it just like an ordinary html. Click the demo link below.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vU3VD/)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<homepages xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<homepage xlink:type="simple"
xlink:href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</homepage>

<homepage xlink:type="simple"
xlink:href="http://www.w3.org">Visit W3C</homepage>

</homepages>
```

**CSS**

```
homepage{
    color:red;
}
```